# Default Argument in non-inline Constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, default-parameters

I've written a Cell class. When I write constructor with default parameters as inline function, there is no problem

```
cell.h
    Class Cell{
    public:
        Cell(int x, int y, char sign='.'):X(x), Y(y), Sign(sign){}  
    };
```

But if I want to move that implementation in my source file like this:

```
cell.h
        Class Cell{
        public:
            Cell(int x, int y, char sign='.');
        };
cell.cpp
    Cell::Cell(int x, int y, char sign='.'):X(x), Y(y), Sign(sign){}
```

Compiler says:

```
Reversi.cpp:1144:43: error: default argument given for parameter 3 of ‘Cell::Cell(int, int, char)’ [-fpermissive]
     Cell::Cell(int x, int y, char sign='.'):X(x), Y(y), Sign(sign){}    
                                           ^
In file included from Reversi.cpp:7:0:
Reversi.h:16:5: note: previous specification in ‘Cell::Cell(int, int, char)’ here
     Cell(int x, int y, char sign='.');    
     ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to specify the default parameters in both files.  Only do it within the Header File, and the compiler will stop complaining.

cell.h

```
Class Cell
{
    public:
    Cell(int x, int y, char sign);
};
```

cell.cpp

```
Cell::Cell(int x, int y, char sign='.'):X(x), Y(y), Sign(sign)
{
}
```

Comment: Didn't work.
Reversi.cpp:1045:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘Cell::Cell(int, int)’

Comment: @thoron Make sure you remove the one in the .cpp, not .h

Comment: You should provide default parameters in the header file and not in the cpp file overwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the default argument only in the member function declaration within the class definition in the header. Otherwise all other modules that include the header will know nothing about the default argument.

You may not declare a default argument for the same parameter more than one time in the same declarative region and the compiler says about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create two implementations or provide two versions of default parameters.

You should provide default parameters in the header file and provide either inline implementation in the header file or in the correspondent cpp file.

cell.h

```
#pragma once

class Cell {
public:
  Cell(int x, int y, char sign = '.');

  int X;
  int Y;
  char Sign;
};
```

cell.cpp

```
#include "cell.h"

Cell::Cell(int x, int y, char sign): X(x), Y(y), Sign(sign) {}
```